# Find a specific node from next parent

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am preparing an application in C# in which I have to deal with xml content.

```
<Document>
    <SW.Blocks.FC ID="0">
        <ObjectList>
            <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="4" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
                <AttributeList>
                    <NetworkSource>
                        <StructuredText xmlns="http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/NetworkSource/StructuredText/v3">
                        <NewLine Num="2" UId="116" />
                        <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="117">
                            <Symbol UId="118">
                              <Component Name="TP40" UId="119" />
                              <Token Text="." UId="120" />
                              <Component Name="IN" UId="121" />
                              <Token Text="." UId="122" />
                              <Component Name="StopSeg" UId="123" />
                              <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="3" BitOffset="3024" Informative="true" />
                            </Symbol>
                        </Access>
                        <Blank Num="29" UId="124" />
                        <Token Text=":=" UId="125" />
                        <Blank Num="1" UId="126" />
                        <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="127">
                        <Symbol UId="128">
                          <Component Name="I_TP40B1" UId="129" />
                          <Address Area="Input" Type="Bool" BitOffset="1026" Informative="true" />
                        </Symbol>
                        </Access>
                        <Token Text=";" UId="130" />
                        <NewLine Num="1" UId="131" />
                    </NetworkSource>
                </AttributeList>
            </SW.Blocks.CompileUnit>
        </ObjectList>
    </SW.Blocks.FC>
</Document>
```

From the given user input "StopSeg", I need to get the component node with Name="I_TP40B1". Can anybody please help me writing XPath for this? or any code in C#?

Comment: I wasn't the "downvoter", but you should provide some basic code yourself. This is a help site for programmers, not one where you can hire programmers for free. Btw... there are several ways to use XML in C#. You should choose one yourself and then, if you get stuck because of lack of knowledge, please ask specific questions about the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing forward slash in the tag StructuredText.  I would use the library Xml Linq instead of XPath.  See code below for sample

You xml isn't idented very well.  User following

```
<Document>
    <SW.Blocks.FC ID="0">
        <ObjectList>
            <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="4" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
                <AttributeList>
                    <NetworkSource>
                        <StructuredText xmlns="http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/NetworkSource/StructuredText/v3"/>
                        <NewLine Num="2" UId="116" />
                        <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="117">
                            <Symbol UId="118">
                                <Component Name="TP40" UId="119" />
                                <Token Text="." UId="120" />
                                <Component Name="IN" UId="121" />
                                <Token Text="." UId="122" />
                                <Component Name="StopSeg" UId="123" />
                                <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="3" BitOffset="3024" Informative="true" />
                            </Symbol>
                        </Access>
                        <Blank Num="29" UId="124" />
                        <Token Text=":=" UId="125" />
                        <Blank Num="1" UId="126" />
                        <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="127">
                            <Symbol UId="128">
                                <Component Name="I_TP40B1" UId="129" />
                                <Address Area="Input" Type="Bool" BitOffset="1026" Informative="true" />
                            </Symbol>
                        </Access>
                        <Token Text=";" UId="130" />
                        <NewLine Num="1" UId="131" />
                    </NetworkSource>
                </AttributeList>
            </SW.Blocks.CompileUnit>
        </ObjectList>
    </SW.Blocks.FC>
</Document>





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement symbol = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Symbol").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = symbol.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement component = symbol.Element(ns + "Component");
            string name = (string)component.Attribute("Name");

        }
    }
}
```